# Merge CSVs using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge multiple CSVs using python. The issue I am running into is that each file has a 3 rows of headers. How do I get rid of the 2nd and 3rd row of headers on all the files (just keeping the main header in the 1st row or each file) before merging them?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should use the `skiprows` parameter of `read_csv` originally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe) with `skiprows` parameter of course

Comment: What if I wanted to have all 3 rows of headers to remain at the top of the file?

Comment: using header = [0,1,2] is causing my date/time column to not be in the 1st column, but in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
all_filenames = ['f1.csv','f2.csv','f3.csv']
temp=[]
for f in range(len(all_filenames)):
    if f==0:
        temp.append(pd.read_csv(all_filenames[f]))
    else:
        temp.append(pd.read_csv(all_filenames[f]), skiprows=[0])
combined_csv = pd.concat(temp)
```